# google maps flight path

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a map with a lot of flight paths, gathered from a database.
The method i use could probably be improved a little:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates1 = [ 
new google.maps.LatLng(53.63384159955519, 10.005816800985485), 
new google.maps.LatLng(40.689837457540044, -74.17809198377654) 
];
var flightPath1 = new google.maps.Polyline({ 
path: flightPlanCoordinates1, 
geodesic: true, 
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0, 
strokeWeight: 2 
});
flightPath1.setMap(map);
...
```

The above will be looped over and over to show all the routes collected from the database.

So my question is, if it would be possible to simplify this, so that all of the above does not have to be looped, only the coordinates.

What i'm thinking is that a "break" function for "flightPlanCoordinates1", to break for each route, would be a good solution.

Appreciate any help

Comment: It has been done already ;-) http://www.flightradar24.com/ (click on the plane to see the path)

Comment: Well that does not help me in my project, unless flightradar is open source...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define your polyline options:

```
var pathOptions = { 
    geodesic: true, 
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0, 
    strokeWeight: 2 
};
```

Then in your loop you can create the polyline with the options:

```
var path = new google.maps.Polyline(pathOptions);
```

Then get the start and end points (where start_lat/lng end_lat/lng are your coordinates):

```
var start_point = new google.maps.LatLng(start_lat, start_lng);
var end_point = new google.maps.LatLng(end_lat, end_lng);
```

Then apply it to the polyline and set it on the map:

```
path.getPath().setAt(0, start_point);
path.getPath().setAt(1, end_point);

path.setMap(map);
```

You get the idea?